# Multiples Odoo containers with multiples Postgresql containers

Tags: docker, containers, odoo

I'm trying to setup several Odoo instances with Docker, each Odoo instance with its own Postgresql container.

I followed this doc (https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo?tab=description)
So I have 2 Odoo containers, 2 Postgresql containers.

But both Odoo instances are pointing to the first Postgresql container.

**Here is the configuration I did :**

> docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e
>   POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name db postgres:10
>
> docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo

---

> docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e
>   POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name db_2 postgres:10
>
> docker run -p 8070:8069 --name odoo_2 --link db_2:db_2 -t odoo
>
> > **Here I also tried db:db_2, db_2:db**

I'm sure you get it, but just to be a little bit more graphical :)

[image]

#### #

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link parameter need to map the container name to alias used in Odoo container. Default Odoo Docker uses alias `db` to reference to database container. Your database container is named `db_2`. To connect these, run Odoo container like this:

```
docker run -p 8070:8069 --name odoo_2 --link db_2:db -t odoo
```

Working example of linking and aliases with Odoo containers can be found in this blog post: https://unkkuri.com/blog/unkkuri-blog-1/post/odoo-13-in-docker-container-27

Please note that the link parameter in Docker is a legacy feature. More information can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/